# Focusing the Current Window & Minimizing All of the Others

Tags: ubuntu, window-management

Is there a way to focus the current window and minimize all of the others through the command line?  For example, if the active window is Chrome, then if I execute this command, it will minimize all of the windows except for Chrome.  I'm using Ubuntu in case it's relevant.

Comment: The linked A below was the first result when I Googled. Please do try to search before dumping Q's into the site. A simple search would've answered your Q. I searched for "minimize all windows linux except main one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bringing this method described in various blog posts and on Ask Ubuntu to U&L as well. This is verbatim from the AU answer.

---

It is possible to achieve this with a python script. The script requires `python-wnck` and `python-gtk` to be installed in order to work, although I think these are installed by default anyway.

Copy and paste this into a text editor and save in a sensible place (eg. as *minimise.py* in your home folder):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
import gtk

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

windows = screen.get_windows()
active = screen.get_active_window()

for w in windows:
    if not w == active:
        w.minimize()
```

You can then set up the keyboard shortcut by opening Keyboard Shortcuts.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts in Dash]

Click on *Add* to create a new shortcut.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts window]

Use the command `bash -c 'python ~/minimise.py'` (this is assuming you saved it as *minimise.py* in your home folder).

[image: create shortcut]

You can then assign your preferred keyboard combination to this action.

The script will minimise all non-active windows. I don't think this is very useful for your use case because you will want to have all of the Gimp windows open. You can use a slightly different script to minimise all windows that aren't from the current application instead:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
import gtk

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

windows = screen.get_windows()
active_app = screen.get_active_window().get_application()

for w in windows:
    if not w.get_application() == active_app:
        w.minimize()
```