# python script to minimize all but one window kills panel

Tags: python, xfce, window-management

I was following the guide [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/focusing-the-current-window-minimizing-all-of-the-others?newreg=f3bf9a5333154b3ca56268773ed715f4)
to make a keyboard shortcut that would minimize all windows except the current one via this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
import gtk

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

windows = screen.get_windows()
active = screen.get_active_window()

for w in windows:
    if not w == active:
            w.minimize()
```

It works, except it also kills my panel which leaves my desktop nearly unusable.

How should I modify the script so that it works without killing my panel?

I'm in Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Xfce version 4.12.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using any of the Gtk stuff. Let's remove the cruft.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
windows = screen.get_windows()
active = screen.get_active_window()

for w in windows:
    if not w == active:
            w.minimize()
```

You can use criteria other than `w == active` to exclude windows. Check the documentation (`pydoc wnck`, unfortunately it's little more than an automatically-generated list of methods) or do a bit of interactive exploration to see what method is available on windows:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wnck
>>> screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
>>> active = screen.get_active_window()
>>> dir(active)
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__gdoc__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gobject_init__', '__grefcount__', '__gt__', '__gtype__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'activate', 'activate_transient', 'chain', 'close', 'connect', 'connect_after', 'connect_object', 'connect_object_after', 'disconnect', 'disconnect_by_func', 'emit', 'emit_stop_by_name', 'freeze_notify', 'get_actions', 'get_application', 'get_class_group', 'get_client_window_geometry', 'get_data', 'get_geometry', 'get_group_leader', 'get_icon', 'get_icon_is_fallback', 'get_icon_name', 'get_mini_icon', 'get_name', 'get_pid', 'get_properties', 'get_property', 'get_screen', 'get_session_id', 'get_session_id_utf8', 'get_sort_order', 'get_state', 'get_transient', 'get_window_type', 'get_workspace', 'get_xid', 'handler_block', 'handler_block_by_func', 'handler_disconnect', 'handler_is_connected', 'handler_unblock', 'handler_unblock_by_func', 'has_icon_name', 'has_name', 'is_above', 'is_active', 'is_below', 'is_fullscreen', 'is_in_viewport', 'is_maximized', 'is_maximized_horizontally', 'is_maximized_vertically', 'is_minimized', 'is_most_recently_activated', 'is_on_workspace', 'is_pinned', 'is_shaded', 'is_skip_pager', 'is_skip_tasklist', 'is_sticky', 'is_visible_on_workspace', 'keyboard_move', 'keyboard_size', 'make_above', 'make_below', 'maximize', 'maximize_horizontally', 'maximize_vertically', 'minimize', 'move_to_workspace', 'needs_attention', 'notify', 'or_transient_needs_attention', 'pin', 'props', 'set_data', 'set_fullscreen', 'set_geometry', 'set_icon_geometry', 'set_properties', 'set_property', 'set_skip_pager', 'set_skip_tasklist', 'set_sort_order', 'set_window_type', 'shade', 'stick', 'stop_emission', 'thaw_notify', 'transient_is_most_recently_activated', 'unmake_above', 'unmake_below', 'unmaximize', 'unmaximize_horizontally', 'unmaximize_vertically', 'unminimize', 'unpin', 'unshade', 'unstick', 'weak_ref']
>>> active.get_name()
'pts/16:  ~   python'
>>> active.is_sticky()
False
```

A sticky window is one that's present on every desktop. These are typically desktop environment widgets that should always be present on the screen, so they shouldn't be minimized. If that isn't enough, you can try matching by name or by other properties.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
windows = screen.get_windows()
active = screen.get_active_window()

for w in windows:
    if not (w == active or w.is_sticky()):
            w.minimize()
```

Comment: Weird.  I'm trying your suggestion, but I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wnck'`  wnck seems to be installed, and I was not getting that error with my first attempt.

Comment: @RobCreel Maybe you only installed it for Python 2/3 and you've switched from Python 2/3 to 3/2?

Comment: That seems plausible. Likely even.  I'm learning to code now, so I've been tinkering with my Python setup.  I'll have to look up how to switch back or install `wnck`  for both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer that you are looking for, but would not be easier to use the window manager shortcuts to hide all `Ctrl + Alt + d` and then open the last active view with `Alt + Tab`? or even change those to make a command that executes both?

Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533515/xubuntu-14-04-change-minimize-all-windows-show-desktop) can help with that.

If your question is about the syntax... I think that 
the functionality that you are seeking is the one from the second script from your guide

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
import gtk

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

windows = screen.get_windows()
active_app = screen.get_active_window().get_application()

for w in windows:
    if not w.get_application() == active_app:
        w.minimize()
```

Comment: This could work, although `Alt + Tab`  does not open the last active window.  Rather, it opens the window that it would have opened had the desktop not  been shown in the first place, second in the list.  At least that's the behavior for me.

It would have to be something like, `Ctrl + Shift + d` then `Alt + Tab`, and then while still holding `Alt` hit `Left` to go back to the first window in the list.  But I'm not good enough at scripting yet to do that on my own.